# angular factories, struggle to consistently share data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm working on ticketing application and for the first time use Angular. My issue is to share and update data between factory and controller.

I've one factory and controller that works as expected, but then when I try to implement the same thing between another controller and another factory, the thing do not work as expected.

Here is working example

```
var PageStatsFactory = function ($http, $q)
{
    var pageStatsObj = {};

    pageStatsObj.pageStats = {          
    };

    pageStatsObj.getTicketStats = function ()
    {
        var data = $.param({});
        $http.post('/Home/getIndexPageStats', data)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            var stats = data.stats;

            pageStatsObj.pageStats.total = stats.total_tickets;
            pageStatsObj.pageStats.new_tickets = stats.new_tickets;
            pageStatsObj.pageStats.old_tickets = stats.old_tickets;
            pageStatsObj.pageStats.old_tickets = stats.closed_tickets;
            pageStatsObj.pageStats.today_tickets = stats.today_tickets;
            pageStatsObj.pageStats.lastweek_tickets = stats.sevenday_tickets;                                       

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config)
        {

        });
    }

    return pageStatsObj;
}

angular.module('HelpDesk')
    .factory('PageStatsFactory', ['$http', '$q', PageStatsFactory]);
```

and in the controller I simply have

```
$scope.pageStats = PageStatsFactory.pageStats;
```

The somewhere down the line I have and init function which contains

```
//getting ticket stats
PageStatsFactory.getTicketStats();
```

And every time I run the init the initial **pageStatsObj.pageStats** gets updated with the new values.

I'm trying to implement same mechanism between another factory and controler, and for some reason I'm not getting the updated factory values.

here is controller:

```
 var ShowTicketCtr = function ($scope, ShowTicketFactory)
{               
    $scope.ticket = ShowTicketFactory.ticket;
    $scope.ticketItems = ShowTicketFactory.ticketItems;


    //initialize controler
    init();
    function init()
    {
        $scope.ticket.length = 0;
        ShowTicketFactory.getTicket();
    }
}

angular.module('HelpDesk')
    .controller('ShowTicketCtr', ['$scope', 'ShowTicketFactory', ShowTicketCtr]);
```

And my factory

```
var ShowTicketFactory = function ($http, $q)
{
    var showTicketObj = {};
    showTicketObj.ticket = {};
    showTicketObj.ticketItems = [];

    showTicketObj.getTicket = function ()
    {
        //var deferred = $q.defer();
        var ticket_id = showTicketObj.getParameterByName("id");
        var data = JSON.stringify({ id: ticket_id });

        $http.post('/Tickets/GetTicketInfo', data)
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                var data = response.data;

                showTicketObj.ticket = data.ticket;
                showTicketObj.ticketItems = data.ticketItems;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {                  
            });            
    }


    showTicketObj.getParameterByName = function (name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    return showTicketObj;
}


angular.module('HelpDesk')
    .factory('ShowTicketFactory', ['$http', '$q', ShowTicketFactory]);
```

As I said I would like the $scope.ticket get updated values every time it changes inside the factory, but for some reason its not happening.

I've debugged the factory and it does get proper values, I can even return them if I use promise object, but I would really like to have the same mechanism of data exchange as in the first example I gave.

I would appreciate if anyone can chaim in and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are breaking the reference to the objects when you reassign them. `showTicketObj.ticket = data.ticket;` creates a new object which is different than the object that is referenced in controller

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Would you mind explaining a bit in more detail, I'm somewhat confused. What would be a proper way for me to assign the object then?

Comment: populate existing array instead of reassigning new array. For object extend existing object instead of reassigning new one

Comment: @charlietfl you absolutely correct. I've tried your suggestion and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.